# Excel / MS Query = How to show `loading` while it loads new data with parameter change

Tags: excel, loading, ms-query

Im using Excel + `MS Query` to load data from database. This query includes some parameters, however since the complex queries takes a few secs to process.

I wonder if there is a way to show `loading` while it loads new data with parameter change? (Like we do in AJAX calls on web)

Thanks

Comment: You just want the text "loading" to be shown on the screen?

Comment: yep that could do